# Msbuild fails to compile a Silverlight solution/project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight, command-line, msbuild

I can't seem to compile the silverlight 3 project from the command line. It comes back with

> MSBUILD : error : Test page creation failed. Unknown error "-1".
>   c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(3329,9): error
>    MSB3491: Could not write lines to file "obj\Debug\HeadsetClient.csproj.FileLis
>   tAbsolute.txt". Unknown error "-1".

Everything else works great on the machine - VS2008 is able to compile everything fine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the path of your project is too long... Can you try to move your project to shorter location like C: or D:?

OR

Can you check whether you added that file or anything under OBJ to TFS? If yes then please remove them from TFS.

Comment: Nope.  None of these fixed the issue.